# How to set maxLength in material ui's <Input /> tag

Tags: reactjs, input, material-ui

```js
<Input
     name="location"
     value={this.state.location}
     inputProps={{
         maxLength: 6,
     }}
     //other props
/>
```

I am using this but this is not working

Tried this but it is not working

Comment: What's the error?

Answer (score 0):

The `inputProps` works on a MUI `<TextField` and the `maxLength`with a type "text"

```
<TextField
    type="text"
    name="location"
    value={this.state.location}
    inputProps={{maxLength: 6,}}
  />
```